# How can I pass an object through $stateParams?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got a ui-router application with a large number of states, and I need to be able to pass a model through $stateParams.  On every $http request, I check the response for a "STATE" parameter, which is returned from the server. If it exists, I execute `$state.go(STATE)`.

So effectively, I've got my `$stateProvider`:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('Account', {url: '/Account', template: '<ui-view/>'})
    .state('Account.name', {
        url: '/Name',
        templateUrl: 'app/Account/partials/Name.html',
        controller: 'AccountNameController as nameVm'
    })
```

And many more states that look just like this.

I have a data model that is just a factory with an object that is get and set via functions.  So whenever I call saveAccount(), it takes the model and sends it to a Web API backend.  The backend verifies the data and sends it back with a STATE parameter (either `account.invalid`, `account.valid`, or `account.needsMoreInfo`).  Here's my $httpInterceptor

```
.factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q', '$injector',
        function ($q,$injector) {
            return {
                'response': function(response) {
                    if(response.data.state){
                        $injector.get('$state').go(response.data.state, response.data.account);
                    }
                    return response;
                }
            };
        }
    ])
```

As you can see, I'm trying to send the account through the stateparams.

In the controller, I basically need to be able to say `vm.account = $stateParams.account`

### My question is:

How can I modify my $states to both have a named controller and also take a state parameter and access that from the controller?

The reason I'm not passing the data through a service is because there are multiple models, so I can't just provide the name of the service in the $httpInterceptor because it isn't constant.

## EDIT: Figured it out

Here's what my controller needed to have in it: 
    if ($stateParams && $stateParams.data){
                vm.Account = $stateParams.data;
            }

And here's what the state ended up looking like:

```
.state('taxAccount.invalid', {
            url: '/Invalid?params',
            templateUrl: 'app/TaxAccount/partials/Invalid.html',
            controller: 'taxAccountInvalidController as invalidVm',
            params:{data:null}
        })
```

I didn't realize I could put `params:{data:null}`.  I thought the stateParams had to go in the controller declaration in the state configuration.

Comment: Named controller should work as is (see [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#controllers)). Define [`params`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider#methods_state) in your state configuration and inject `$stateParams` into your controller to access the state parameters.

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer? That way this won't show up as an unanswered question.

Comment: Yep.  Sorry, I didn't think I could answer my own question for two days, but it looks like I just can't accept it until then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what my controller needed to have in it: 
    if ($stateParams && $stateParams.data){
                vm.Account = $stateParams.data;
            }

And here's what the state ended up looking like:

```
.state('taxAccount.invalid', {
            url: '/Invalid?params',
            templateUrl: 'app/TaxAccount/partials/Invalid.html',
            controller: 'taxAccountInvalidController as invalidVm',
            params:{data:null}
        })
```

I didn't realize I could put `params:{data:null}`.  I thought the stateParams had to go in the controller declaration in the state configuration.